# Windows Form フォルダ内の画像を一枚ずつPictureBoxに表示していく

Tags: c#, winforms

はじめまして。
C#初心者で色々と分からないため、質問させていただきます。

現在、C#にてフォルダ内の画像を取得し、一枚ずつPicutreBoxに動画のように表示していこうとしているのですが、なかなかうまくいかず困っております。

現状試したことは、GIFに変換生成してからPictureBoxに表示するですが、これはGIFが再生されない上、メモリを多く食ってしまうため、諦めました。

お知恵を拝借できれば幸いです。

Comment: こういうサンプルがありますので参考に。[C# Winform Animated Image Slide Show in Winform](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/C-Winform-Animated-Image-97739360)

Answer (score 1):

質問文から、求める回答が読み取れませんでした。
類似の質問を見かけることの多い、下記3点のサンプルコードをご提示します。

1. 非常に素早くアニメーション表示をする方法を知りたい
2. n秒ごとに画像を切り替えてスライドショーを表示したい
3. マウスクリックやキー入力でアニメーションする方法を知りたい

サンプルコードを動作させるにはWindows Formsに`PictureBox(pictureBox1)`と`Timer(timer1)`を貼り付けます。

`Form`に`Load`と`Shown`イベントを、`PictureBox`に`MouseClick`イベントを追加し、`Timer`に`Tick`イベントを追加する必要があります。

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int Index;
        private bool IsMouseMode;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsMouseMode = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //アニメーションの元画像を64枚作成しておく
            CreateSampleImage();
        }

        private void CreateSampleImage()
        {
            var bmp = new Bitmap(64, 64);
            var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 64);
            //背景を適当に塗りつぶし
            var zip = from x in range
                      from y in range
                      select new { x, y };
            zip.ToList().ForEach(p => { bmp.SetPixel(p.x, p.y, Color.Black); });
            //正弦派的なお絵描き
            range.Select(x =>
            {
                var rad = System.Math.PI * x / 12d;
                return new { x = x, y = (int)(Math.Sin(rad) * 5 + bmp.Height / 2) };
            }).ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                bmp.SetPixel(p.x, p.y, Color.White);
                bmp.Save(string.Format("{0}.png", p.x), ImageFormat.Png);
            });
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Text = "最速アニメーション";
            DrawRapidly();
            Text = "10FPSアニメーション";
            DrawOnTimer(100);  //終了するとクリックアニメーションモードになる
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// とにかく最速でアニメーション描画する
        /// </summary>
        private void DrawRapidly()
        {
            pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = true;
            Enumerable.Range(0, 64).ToList().ForEach(i =>
            {
                pictureBox1.Load(string.Format("{0}.png", i));
                pictureBox1.Update();
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// intervelの周期に従って描画する
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="interval"></param>
        private void DrawOnTimer(int interval)
        {
            timer1.Interval = interval;
            pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = false;
            Index = 0;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.LoadAsync(string.Format("{0}.png", Index));
            pictureBox1.Update();
            Index++;
            if(64 <= Index)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                DrawOnClick();
            }
        }

        private void DrawOnClick()
        {
            Text = "クリックアニメーション";
            IsMouseMode = true;
            Index = 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 左クリックで線が伸びる。それ以外のクリックで線が縮むよう描画する
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsMouseMode) return;
            Index += e.Button == MouseButtons.Left ? 1 : -1;
            Index = Math.Max(Math.Min(Index, 63), 0);
            pictureBox1.LoadAsync(string.Format("{0}.png", Index));
        }
    }
}
```

もしも質問したい内容が下記のような場合は、具体的な質問やサンプルコードの追記をご検討ください。

1. PictureBoxでGIFを再生する方法が分からない
2. GIF作成時のメモリ不足対策がしたい
3. ゲームプログラミングで用いるスプライトアニメーションのように、複数の画像を連結した1つのPNGとしてロードし、画像を部分的に切り出すことで疑似的なアニメーションを実装したい